# using quartz static field in spring xml

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

```
<beans xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

 <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
  <property name="misfireInstruction">
    <util:constant static-field="org.quartz.CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW"/>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm receiving org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'util:constant'.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined xml namespace, but not schema location. You should add:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"       
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

(for Sprint 3, for Spring 2.5 it would be spring-util-2.5.xsd etc.).

Comment: do i need two for the schema location? Can I just use the one with spring-util-3.0.xsd?

Comment: schema locations are pairs: location name and xsd location. You need also schema location for beans, updated

Comment: still having the same problem after adding the pair.

Comment: What version of Spring you are using? you can also try http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using

```
<bean id="myField"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
<property name="staticField" value="java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE"/>
</bean>
```